# Convert disk space from Bytes to GB

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have this batch command:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption ^, freespace') do echo %%a %%b
```

How to convert the result into GB?
Why will the result appear if **echo is off** when the result is printed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Command line get disk space in GB](https://superuser.com/questions/896764/windows-command-line-get-disk-space-in-gb)

Comment: Why the *bash* tag?

Comment: @Berend probably a typo from [tag:batch]

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims==" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption, freespace /format:value') do set /a gb=%%b / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 & echo %%a %gb% GB
```